# How to pass a string or class to a method to create instance

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am to use the following method, it works by passing a type to it such as `obj.addComponent(MyClass)`. This works just fine.

I tried to modify the `type` parameter by adding `| string` to it, but it now gives me errors saying:

> Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.

Is there anyway for me to modify this so that I can pass either a Class name in or a string version of the class?

Here is what I have that doesn't work:

```
public addComponent<T extends Component>(type: ComponentType<T> | string): T {
    let comp;
    comp = new type() as T;
    comp.name = comp.constructor.name;
}
```

Here are its dependencies:

```
class Component extends Obj {

}

interface ComponentType<T extends Component> {
    new(): T;
}
```

I have tried using `Object.create()`, which works fine, but then I get a new error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'name' of object '[object Object]'

**Edit:**

In the end I would like to be able to pass the following to `addComponent`:

```
obj.addComponent(MyClass);
```

Or

```
obj.addComponent("MyClass");
```

Comment: Since you basically go `new type()`, you'll have to change that part. If all the 'classes' share a namespace, you can use your current version if type is an object or `new namespace[type]` if type is a string.

Comment: I am not using a namespace for the passed in value.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. Do you want to know how to instantiate a class by its string name?

Comment: Yes, or by passing a class. Let me update the example...

Comment: @NitzanTomer I have updated my initial post with an example of how I would like to use the method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to get the class using a name in javascript, it doesn't have something similar to the java `ClassLoader`.
You can get around that by creating your own mechanism, and there are probably many ways to do so, but here are 3 options.

(1) Maintain a registry for your component classes:

```
const REGISTRY: { [name: string]: ComponentType<Component> } = {};

class Component {}

class MyComponent1 extends Component {}
REGISTRY["MyComponent1"] = MyComponent1;

class MyComponent2 extends Component {}
REGISTRY["MyComponent2"] = MyComponent2;

type ComponentType<T extends Component> = {
    new(): T;
}

function factory<T extends Component>(type: ComponentType<T> | string): T {
    return typeof type === "string" ?
        new REGISTRY[type]() as T:
        new type();
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20REGISTRY%3A%20%7B%20%5Bname%3A%20string%5D%3A%20ComponentType%3CComponent%3E%20%7D%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Component%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20MyComponent1%20extends%20Component%20%7B%7D%0D%0AREGISTRY%5B%22MyComponent1%22%5D%20%3D%20MyComponent1%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20MyComponent2%20extends%20Component%20%7B%7D%0D%0AREGISTRY%5B%22MyComponent2%22%5D%20%3D%20MyComponent2%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20ComponentType%3CT%20extends%20Component%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%09new()%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20factory%3CT%20extends%20Component%3E(type%3A%20ComponentType%3CT%3E%20%7C%20string)%3A%20T%20%7B%0D%0A%09return%20typeof%20type%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22string%22%20%3F%0D%0A%09%09new%20REGISTRY%5Btype%5D()%20as%20T%3A%0D%0A%09%09new%20type()%3B%0D%0A%7D))

If you go with this approach then I suggest to make the `REGISTRY` an object that holds the collection, that way you can add the ctor only and get the name from that.

There's a variant for this and that's to use a decorator:

```
function register(constructor: typeof Component) {
    REGISTRY[(constructor as any).name] = constructor;
}

@register
class MyComponent1 extends Component {}

@register
class MyComponent2 extends Component {}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20REGISTRY%3A%20%7B%20%5Bname%3A%20string%5D%3A%20ComponentType%3CComponent%3E%20%7D%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20register(constructor%3A%20typeof%20Component)%20%7B%0D%0A%09REGISTRY%5B(constructor%20as%20any).name%5D%20%3D%20constructor%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Component%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%40register%0D%0Aclass%20MyComponent1%20extends%20Component%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%40register%0D%0Aclass%20MyComponent2%20extends%20Component%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20ComponentType%3CT%20extends%20Component%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%09new()%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20factory%3CT%20extends%20Component%3E(type%3A%20ComponentType%3CT%3E%20%7C%20string)%3A%20T%20%7B%0D%0A%09return%20typeof%20type%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22string%22%20%3F%0D%0A%09%09new%20REGISTRY%5Btype%5D()%20as%20T%3A%0D%0A%09%09new%20type()%3B%0D%0A%7D))

(2) Wrap the components in a namespace (As @Shilly suggested in a comment):

```
namespace components {
    export class Component {}
    export class MyComponent1 extends Component {}
    export class MyComponent2 extends Component {}

    export type ComponentType<T extends Component> = {
        new(): T;
    }

    export function forName(name: string): ComponentType<Component> {
        if (this[name] && this[name].prototype instanceof Component) {
            return this[name];
        }
    }
}

function factory<T extends components.Component>(type: components.ComponentType<T> | string): T {
    return typeof type === "string" ?
        new (components.forName(type))() as T:
        new type();
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=namespace%20components%20%7B%0D%0A%09export%20class%20Component%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%09export%20class%20MyComponent1%20extends%20Component%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%09export%20class%20MyComponent2%20extends%20Component%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09export%20type%20ComponentType%3CT%20extends%20Component%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09new()%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09export%20function%20forName(name%3A%20string)%3A%20ComponentType%3CComponent%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09for%20(let%20key%20in%20this)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%09console.log(%60%24%7B%20key%20%7D%3A%20%24%7B%20this%5Bkey%5D%20%7D%60)%3B%0D%0A%09%09%09if%20(key%20%3D%3D%3D%20name%20%26%26%20this%5Bkey%5D.prototype%20instanceof%20Component)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this%5Bkey%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%09%09%7D%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20factory%3CT%20extends%20components.Component%3E(type%3A%20components.ComponentType%3CT%3E%20%7C%20string)%3A%20T%20%7B%0D%0A%09return%20typeof%20type%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22string%22%20%3F%0D%0A%09%09new%20(components.forName(type))()%20as%20T%3A%0D%0A%09%09new%20type()%3B%0D%0A%7D))

If you're going with this approach then you need to make sure that all the component classes are exported.

(3) Use eval

```
class Component {}
class MyComponent1 extends Component {}
class MyComponent2 extends Component {}

type ComponentType<T extends Component> = {
    new(): T;
}

function factory<T extends Component>(type: ComponentType<T> | string): T {
    return typeof type === "string" ?
        new (eval(type))() as T:
        new type();
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Component%20%7B%7D%0D%0Aclass%20MyComponent1%20extends%20Component%20%7B%7D%0D%0Aclass%20MyComponent2%20extends%20Component%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20ComponentType%3CT%20extends%20Component%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%09new()%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20factory%3CT%20extends%20Component%3E(type%3A%20ComponentType%3CT%3E%20%7C%20string)%3A%20T%20%7B%0D%0A%09return%20typeof%20type%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22string%22%20%3F%0D%0A%09%09new%20(eval(type))()%20as%20T%3A%0D%0A%09%09new%20type()%3B%0D%0A%7D))

This isn't a recommended approach, and you can [read all about the cons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don't_use_eval_needlessly!) in using `eval` in a lot of places.
But it's still an option so I'm listing it.

Comment: Example 3 seems as if it is the most dynamic. I am however removing all characters that are not alphanumeric or an underscore, `let evalT = type.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/g, '');` then I am passing that result to eval.

Comment: I prefer the 1st with the decorators, it's easy to use and robust. With `eval` things can go wrong.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to instantiate classes by their name as String if they are in a namespace :

```
var variableName: any = new YourNamespace[YourClassNameString](ClassParameters);
```

For exmaple, this should work :

```
namespace myNamespace {
    export class myClass  {
        example() {
            return true;
        }
    }
}

var newClass: any = new myNamespace["myClass"](); // <- This loads the class A.
newClass.example();
```

This will instantiate the class `myClass` using the string `"myClass"`.

Thus, to come back to your situation, I think this will work :

```
namespace myNamespace {

    // The dependencies you defined
    export class Component {

    }
    export interface ComponentType<T extends Component> {
        new(): T;
    }

    // Just a class to contain the method's code
    export class Example {
        public addComponent<T extends Component>(type: ComponentType<T> | string): T {
            let result: T;
            if (typeof type === "string") {
                result = new myNamespace[type]();
            } else {
                result = new type();
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you'll be able to do this :

```
let stringToLoad = "Component";
let classToLoad = Component;

let example = new Example();

let result1: Component = example.addComponent(stringToLoad);
let result2: Component = example.addComponent(classToLoad);
```

Playground version with code + test : [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=namespace%20myNamespace%20%7B%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09%2F%2F%20The%20dependencies%20you%20defined%0D%0A%09export%20class%20Component%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09export%20interface%20ComponentType%3CT%20extends%20Component%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09new()%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09%2F%2F%20Just%20a%20class%20to%20contain%20the%20method's%20code%0D%0A%20%20%20%20export%20class%20Example%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20public%20addComponent%3CT%20extends%20Component%3E(type%3A%20ComponentType%3CT%3E%20%7C%20string)%3A%20T%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%09let%20result%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%09%09%09if%20(typeof%20type%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22string%22)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%09%09result%20%3D%20new%20myNamespace%5Btype%5D()%3B%0D%0A%09%09%09%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%09%09result%20%3D%20new%20type()%3B%0D%0A%09%09%09%7D%0D%0A%09%09%09return%20result%3B%0D%0A%09%09%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09%2F%2F%20Test%20the%20function%0D%0A%09export%20class%20Test%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09public%20test()%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%09let%20stringToLoad%20%3D%20%22Component%22%3B%0D%0A%09%09%09let%20classToLoad%20%3D%20Component%3B%0D%0A%09%09%09%0D%0A%09%09%09let%20example%20%3D%20new%20Example()%3B%0D%0A%09%09%09%0D%0A%09%09%09let%20result1%3A%20Component%20%3D%20example.addComponent(stringToLoad)%3B%0D%0A%09%09%09let%20result2%3A%20Component%20%3D%20example.addComponent(classToLoad)%3B%0D%0A%09%09%7D%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D)

Comment: Using a namespace doesn't seem to work in the way that I would like it to. This does work however, just not in the way that I would like it to.

Comment: I'm having difficulty getting this to run. Can't get the playground above to work properly. Please see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39509504/typescript-creating-objects-using-a-string-name