# Creating TypeScript objects dynamically

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Following [a post](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2014/07/creating-typescript-classes-dynamically/) regarding creating objects dynamically in TypeScript, I have the following code used as a factory to create an object from its name:

```
public createComponent(context: Object, componentName: string): ComponentRef<ComponentBase> {
    this.viewContainer.clear();
    var instance = 
        Object.create(context[componentName].prototype); // <-- fails
    let componentFactory =
            this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(instance);
    return <ComponentRef<ComponentBase>> this.viewContainer.createComponent(componentFactory);
}
```

I'm not entirely convinced I understand this `window[suchAndSuch]` syntax: what does it mean? Can't find any documentation for it.

In any event it seems that `window[myClassName]` is undefined, even though the class in question is defined in the same file. I have looked at the Javascript transpiled from the TypeScript, and the class in question is in scope.

I think.

Help!

-- UPDATE --
I have this code, which is part of an Angular 2 application, that is calling the above method to try to get an instance of a component, injectables and all:

```
export class CustomUserComponent implements OnChanges {
    @Input() componentType: string;
    @ViewChild(ComponentDirective) componentAnchor: ComponentDirective;
    ref: ComponentRef<GalleriaComponentBase>;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.ref = this.componentAnchor
            .createComponent(window, this.componentType);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using modules? That is, are you using import/export?  If so then your class is not defined on the `window` object. That post is pretty old (2014), and things can be done better today (probably). Can you include more code and explain your problem and what you want to do?

Comment: For your window[suchAndSuch] comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

Comment: Aha, illumination. Thanks Mike.

Comment: Nitzan, yes I am using modules. Where would the object exist? I am at lunch at the moment so can't post source, but essentially I am trying to create a component from a name that is a string. Possible? That post looks promising.

Comment: (When in say component, I mean an Angular 2 component)

Comment: @NitzanTomer, I have added some more code above, does that help?

Comment: Check my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39105390/how-to-pass-a-string-or-class-to-a-method-to-create-instance/39106914#39106914 Does that help?

Comment: @NitzanTomer checking....please wait. :)

Comment: Hmm @NitzanTomer, did you try this code? I get an error using the decorator: Argument of type 'typeof MyComponent1' is not assignable to parameter of type 'typeof Component'. Are these two not compatible? How does it work with a base class?

Comment: Seems to work: [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20ComponentType%3CT%20extends%20Component%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20new()%3A%20T%3B%0A%7D%0Aclass%20Component%20%7B%7D%0Aconst%20REGISTRY%3A%20%7B%20%5Bname%3A%20string%5D%3A%20ComponentType%3CComponent%3E%20%7D%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0Afunction%20register(constructor%3A%20typeof%20Component)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20REGISTRY%5B(constructor%20as%20any).name%5D%20%3D%20constructor%3B%0A%7D%0A%40register%0Aclass%20MyComponent1%20extends%20Component%20%7B%7D%0A%40register%0Aclass%20MyComponent2%20extends%20Component%20%7B%7D)

Comment: Yes @NitzanTomer, it helped a lot, but I am having issues...

Comment: Hi @NitzanTomer, as I say I am having difficulty getting this to work. Don't understand the meaning of the error. Any chance you could take a look at my post? I'm having difficulty getting this to run. Can't get the playground above to work properly. Please see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39509504/typescript-creating-objects-using-a-string-name Thanks!