# TypeScript: creating objects using a string name

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am getting somewhere with this problem following this [excellent post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39105390/how-to-pass-a-string-or-class-to-a-method-to-create-instance/39106914#39106914) about manifesting objects by name, using the decorator approach. The code compiles, but I receive run-time errors.

I cannot get the playground on the page linked to above to execute: it just leads to a about:blank.

Here is my decorator code:

```
export function RegisterComponent(obj: ComponentType<GalleriaComponentBase>) {
    new ComponentRegistry().RegisterComponent(obj);
}
```

I have tried applying my `@RegisterComponent` decorator to the base class of the components, `obj.name` is then equal to `ComponentBase` which is, of course, no good.

So, I tried applying the decorator to each derived class, but I receive the following run-time error:

```
Argument of type 'typeof RepositoryComponent' is not assignable to parameter of type 'new () => ComponentBase'.
```

`ComponentBase` looks like this:

```
export class GalleriaComponentBase {
    refreshComponent() {};
    getCustomUserComponentTypeFriendlyName() {};
}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Would you mind posting a complete example we can copy and paste.

Comment: You need to post more code of yours, for example what's `ComponentRegistry`?